# Horizon not working in Lumen with redis queue connection?

Tags: laravel, redis, lumen, laravel-queue

I have two projects, one in laravel and other is in Lumen.I am using redis queue for this projects and i have installed horizon to monitor queue in laravel project.Both queue are working with same redis credentilas, but only laravel queue is showing in Horizon.